# DLL call with __stdcall & GetProcAddress() in VS2013

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to call a function from my own DLL, but depending on the calling convention in the DLL project either I can't find the ProcAddress or my stack is getting corrupted. It works perfectly for 3rd Party DLLs so I would like to not change anything in the loading code itself if there is no major problem there. A minimal example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

typedef long (__stdcall* tMyFunction)(int);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  HINSTANCE m_dllHandle = LoadLibrary("MyDll.dll");
  if (m_dllHandle != NULL){
    tMyFunction function = (tMyFunction)GetProcAddress(m_dllHandle, "myFunction");
    if (function != NULL){
      long value = function(1);
      std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }else{
      std::cout << "GetProcAddress() failed" << std::endl;
    }

    FreeLibrary(m_dllHandle);
    m_dllHandle = NULL;
  }else{
    std::cout << "LoadLibrary() failed" << std::endl;
  }
  system("pause");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In the DLL:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) long __stdcall myFunction(int a){
  return 10;
}
```

Result: GetProcAddress() fails

dumpbin /EXPORTS -> _myFunction@4 = _myFunction@4

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) long __cdecl myFunction(int a){
  return 10;
}
```

Result: "Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention." (Because I use __stdcall in loading code and __cdecl in DLL).

dumpbin /EXPORTS -> _myFunction = _myFunction

In 3rd party DLLs, I can see, that "dumpbin /EXPORTS" only shows
myFunction (no underscores, no @4) What can I do to accomplish the same and still be able to load it with the above defined type (`typedef long (__stdcall* tMyFunction)(int);`)? My compiler is "Visual Studio 2013".

Comment: You are exporting the decorated name but passing the undecorated name to `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: I guess its due to the mismatched symbol name. maybe you cab try DEF file to specify exported functions? see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx

Comment: Fyi, `extern C` doesn't stop name decoration, only C++ name mangling. To have no decoration at all you need to use a DEF file as suggested by @KingsleyChen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, the calling convention used by the DLL function must match the function pointer definition you are using.  Since it didn't match, you get the error that you've corrupted the stack.

---

Second, When you use `GetProcAddress` the function name you use in the call to `GetProcAddress` must match **exactly** the exported DLL function name.  It has to match not only on characters, but casing also i.e. `myFunction` is not the same as `MyFunction`.

The exported name in your example is `_myFunction@4`. which means that accessing the function using `GetProcAddress` would be:

```
GetProcAddress(myModuleHandle, "_myFunction@4");
```

There is no getting around having to specify the name this way, since that *is* the name of the function.

So you have two options:

1. Change the code as described above, that is, to use the actual name or
2. Change the DLL so that the exported name is actually `myFunction`

Since we covered the first option, for the second option, you have to rebuild the DLL to use a `Module Definition File` (or simply known as a `.DEF` file) to redefine the name.

Here is a link to what a module definition file is:

[Module Definition File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h.aspx)

So a typical .DEF file would contain this:

```
LIBRARY MyDLL

EXPORTS
    myFunction  @2
```

The `@2` is the `ordinal number`.  For your purposes, it is not important what this number is since there is only one function.  I chose `@2`, but you can choose any number (`@3`, `@4`, or even `@1000` if you desired).  However, if there is more than 1 exported function, the ordinal numbers should be unique, i.e., you can't have two exported functions that have the same ordinal number.

If you save the above contents to a `MyDll.DEF` and added it to the project that builds the DLL (not the project that will use the DLL), you will then need to rebuild the DLL.  Once that's done, the DLL will now have an exported name of `myFunction` without the `@4` decoration and without the underscore.

(Note:  As mentioned by the comment above, the `extern "C"` used does *not* turn off the decoration that Windows uses (the additional underscore and the `@x` appended to the name).  All `extern "C"` does is turn off the C++ name mangling. To turn off the Windows name mangling, that requires the `.DEF` file.)

P.S.  I use a tool called `Dependency Walker` to easily determine what the exported function names are in a DLL.  Since Dependency Walker is a GUI app, the output is a little friendlier than `dumpbin.exe`

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Just to add, you mention that the DLL works flawlessly in other applications.  If those other applications use `import libraries` instead of using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to access the function, then those import libraries automatically handle the translation of `myFunction` to `_myFunction@4`.

That's why it works without issues for these types of applications.  However, when you take the route of `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`, you are not afforded this "help" in getting the name translated, and you're basically on your own.